# How can I know which Callable returned null on RX Java when the exception doesn't give me any more details?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Basically on Crashlytics I'm getting an exception that I understand what it means and how to fix it but I have no idea where it is happening. I don't have any extra details other than this:

```
Fatal Exception: hw0: Callable returned null
       at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
       at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
       at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.onError(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:63)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
       at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)

Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Callable returned null
       at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:228)
       at io.reactivex.internal.functions.ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(ObjectHelper.java:39)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromCallable.subscribeActual(ObservableFromCallable.java:42)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12036)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual(ObservableObserveOn.java:45)
       at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12036)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
       at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:579)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
       at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I use RX in a ton of places so it isn't easy to narrow down where the issue might be.

Is there a way to maybe put a global error handler for RX so I can log more information when this type of thing happens? Or does anyone have any suggestions on how I can narrow this down?

Thanks.

Edit: Just to be clear, I know how to fix this type of error, but I can only fix it if I know which of the many RX calls it is happening on and right now I don't know that.

Comment: isn't this type of error usually caused by missing the `onError` part of an rx function ? `subscibeOn(foo).observeOn(foo).subscribe({//this is success },{ this is an error})`

Comment: Adding in a "BreadCrumb" exception will help (especially in long call chains) - https://rongi.github.io/kotlin-blog/rxjava/2017/09/25/breadcrumbs-rxjava-error-handling.html - this is NOT global, but you could easily create extension functions, or compose functions in java to introduce these into existing rx chains.

Comment: @a_local_nobody yeah there are a few ways to fix it, adding `onError` will fix it. I know how to fix it, I don't know where it is happening.

Comment: Thank you @MarkKeen, I will look into that.

Comment: It's one of your `fromCallable`s. You'll have to put null checking inside those `Callable`s, i.e., `Objects.requireNonNull(result, "Location 1")` etc.

Comment: @akarnokd yes that is correct, I know how to fix the issue however I don't know which `Callable` it is coming from and since there are dozens of `Callables`, it isn't super easy to find. I don't want to just blindly go fix all of them that are spread all over the app.

Comment: Not sure what you expect from us then. RxJava can't tell you because it's after the fact. We can't tell you because we don't even see your code. I see no other way than going in and start adding those requireNonNull calls diligently.

Comment: We use this in our project  and it has helped: https://github.com/uber/RxDogTag